# Howto: Insert a template conditionally in Azure DevOps YAML?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

Here's how I'm trying to accomplish inserting a template conditionally.  Per requirement, I would like to either call fresh-deploy.yml or update.yml based on a pipeline variable supplied at run time.  The user can edit a variable called 'freshInstall' to either true or false.

The main pipeline (entrypoint):

```
# azure-pipelines.yml
variables:
  shouldUpdate: 'false'

jobs:
  - job: TestJob
    pool:
      name: "Vyas' Local Machine"
    steps:
    - checkout: none
    - template: ./testIf.yml
      parameters:
        freshInstall: $(freshInstall)
```

The testif.yml:

```
# testIf.yml
parameters:
  - name: freshInstall
    type: string  # Can't be boolean as runtime supplied variable values ARE strings

steps:

  # set a preexisting variable valued 'false' to 'true'
  - powershell: |
      $shouldUpdate = 'true'
      Write-Host "##vso[task.SetVariable variable=shouldUpdate]$shouldUpdate"
    displayName: 'Set Should Update to $(shouldUpdate)'

  # Check if the parameter 'freshInstall' is passed in correctly
  - script: echo "Should freshInstall ${{ parameters['freshInstall'] }}"
    displayName: 'Is Fresh Install? ${{ parameters.freshInstall }}'

  # Should skip this
  - ${{ if eq(parameters.freshInstall, 'true') }}:
    - template: ./fresh-deploy.yml

  # Shoud include this
  - ${{ if eq(parameters.freshInstall, 'false') }}:
    - template: ./update.yml

  # Check variables vs parameters.  Include as per value set
  - ${{ if eq(variables.shouldUpdate, 'true') }}:
    - template: ./update.yml

  # Use all 3 syntaxes of variable access
  - script: echo "shouldUpdate is variables['shouldUpdate']"
    displayName: "Should Update? variables.shouldUpdate"
```

The mock file for fresh-deploy.yml:

```
# fresh-deploy.yml
steps:
  script: echo 'Kick off fresh deploy!'
```

The mock file for update.yml:

```
# update.yml
steps:
  script: echo 'Updating existing installation!'
```

Critical issue: The expectation is that the update.yml template is inserted and the script run when the variable 'freshInstall' is false.

Nice to know: I was also checking if I could somehow get this to work if it were a variable instead of a parameter. It'd be nice if I could be pointed to what I'm doing wrong with the variable displays.

Here's the result:
[image]

Comment: I did find this link that talks about why it doesn't work: 
 Run time vs. compile time. 
 However, it is not so clear cut https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/653819/yaml-pipeline-conditional-insertion-does-not-work.html

Comment: In the compile time, the 'Set Should Update to false' is not run yet, this means the variable `shouldUpdate`'s value is still 'false'. Change the `Should Update? ` task to - script: echo "shouldUpdate is $(shouldUpdate)" 
       displayName: "Should Update? $(shouldUpdate)" and it will show 
"shouldUpdate is true"
Finishing: Should Update? false, this might be easier to understand.

Comment: @YangShen-MSFT:  then the following should work and it doesn't: 
  - $[ if eq(${{ parameters.freshInstall }}, 'true') ]:
    - template: ./fresh-deploy.yml

Comment: No sir, it has to be the compile time, change it to `$[ <expression> ]` will not change the fact that this expression has to be at compile time. You shall meet the error: [Unexpected Value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/52ONe.png).

Comment: @YangShen-MSFT:  It will be great if you could provide a workaround on how to accomplish conditional insertion using queue time variable values.  Thanks!

Answer (score 20):

This solution now works for me:

```
- ${{ if eq(parameters.generateSwaggerFiles, true) }}:
    - template: generate-swagger-files.yaml
      parameters:
        appName: 'example'
        swaggerVersions:
          - v1
          - v2
```

Check documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops#parameters-to-select-a-template-at-runtime).

Comment: If more conditions are provided, do you know how to split them on multiple lines?
I know the '|' is used on tasks with condition parameter.
But I never saw an example for the conditional templates.
Thx!

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is now solved since runtime parameters are now allowed to be boolean.
Check out [Runtime Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runtime-parameters?view=azure-devops&tabs=script#use-parameters-to-determine-what-steps-run). I had a similar use case and was able to achieve it using this.